# Getting a slice of keys from a map

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

Is there any simpler/nicer way of getting a slice of keys from a map in Go?

Currently I am iterating over the map and copying the keys to a slice:

```golang
i := 0
keys := make([]int, len(mymap))
for k := range mymap {
    keys[i] = k
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 309, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

func main() {
    mymap := make(map[int]string)
    keys := make([]int, 0, len(mymap))
    for k := range mymap {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
}
```

To be efficient in Go, it's important to minimize memory allocations.

Comment: It's slightly better to set the actual size instead of capacity and avoid append altogether. See my answer for details.

Comment: Note that if `mymap` is not a local variable (and is therefore subject to growing/shrinking), this is the only proper solution - it ensures that if the size of `mymap` changes between the initialization of `keys` and the `for` loop, there won't be any out-of-bounds issues.

Comment: maps are not safe under concurrent access, neither solution is acceptable if another goroutine might change the map.

Comment: @VinayPai it is okay to read from a map from multiple goroutines but not write

Comment: @darethas that is a common misconception. The race detector will flag this usage since 1.6. From the release notes: "As always, if one goroutine is writing to a map, no other goroutine should be reading or writing the map concurrently. If the runtime detects this condition, it prints a diagnosis and crashes the program."  https://golang.org/doc/go1.6#runtime

Comment: @vinay-pai Correct, I shouldn't have said okay but safe. Now whether that will result in correct behavior from your program is another story, which you are right.

Comment: @darethas why is this sometimes safe to do and sometimes a problem? From Vinay Pais comment it seems like this is a bad idea in general?

Comment: I'm not a Go expert yet, but I am a computer expert.  I cannot find myself convinced that using append instead of an index is any more efficient, and certainly should not prevent unnecessary memory allocations.  Although, I do understand that the "append" mechanism in Go on a slice allocated with a sufficient capacity is supposed to be as efficient (or nearly so?) as using the index.  I would actually imagine it (nearly immeasurably) _less_ efficient, since append would have to change len of the slice on each iteration.  Then again, the compiler can unroll that part of the loop.

Comment: Has there been a discussion in the Go community about why not add a function similar to Python's `keys` to make code more modular and shorter? There could even be a thread-safe and a non-thread-safe version of it.

Answer (score 566):

This is an old question, but here's my two cents. PeterSO's answer is slightly more concise, but slightly less efficient.  You already know how big it's going to be so you don't even need to use append:

```
keys := make([]int, len(mymap))

i := 0
for k := range mymap {
    keys[i] = k
    i++
}
```

In most situations it probably won't make much of a difference, but it's not much more work, and in my tests (using a map with 1,000,000 random `int64` keys and then generating the array of keys ten times with each method), it was about 20% faster to assign members of the array directly than to use append.

Although setting the capacity eliminates reallocations, append still has to do extra work to check if you've reached capacity on each append.

Comment: This looks exactly the same as the OP's code.  I agree that this is the better way, but I'm curious if I've missed the difference between this answer's code and OP's code.

Comment: Good point, I somehow looked at the other answers and missed that my answer is exactly the same as the OP.  Oh well, at least we now know approximately what the penalty is for using append unnecessarily :)

Comment: Why aren't you using an index with the range, `for i, k := range mymap{`. That way you don't need the i++?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but if you did `i, k := range mymap`, then `i` will be keys and `k` will be values corresponding to those keys in the map. That won't actually help you populate a slice of keys.

Comment: Note that this solution is not recommended if `mymap` is subject to frequent changes - see my comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Maps are not safe for concurrent access, you need a mutex or some other mechanism to prevent more than one goroutine from modifying it while iterating over it.

Comment: I disagree with @DustyW, the append version reads better, is more concise and doesn't require a counter variable.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat. I personally would rather write code that is two lines longer but more efficient.

Comment: I concur with Vinay on efficiency efforts. In this vein, use this tool to spot pre-alloc opportunities in your code: https://github.com/alexkohler/prealloc

Comment: Concurrency can bring some troubles here: if the map size grows while the copy is beeing made, you can end up trying to insert itens past the array limit. In this case, the append solution or the reflect one is better.

Comment: Maps are not safe for concurrent access. You need to rethink the whole solution to make it safe if that's a possibility.

Comment: @Alaska if you're concerned with the cost of allocating one temporary counter variable, but think a function call is going to take less memory you should educate yourself on what actually happens when a function gets called. Hint: It's not a magical incantation that does things for free. If you think the currently accepted answer is safe under concurrent access, you also need to go back to the basics: https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_6.

Comment: Anyone reading this after go 1.10.1 it seems like there's no significant different between assignment and using append https://stackoverflow.com/a/52148380

Answer (score 127):

You also can take an array of keys with type `[]Value` by method `MapKeys` of struct `Value` from package "reflect":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    abc := map[string]int{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "c": 3,
    }

    keys := reflect.ValueOf(abc).MapKeys()

    fmt.Println(keys) // [a b c]
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good approach if there is a chance of a concurrent map access: this won't panic if the map grows during the loop. About performance, I'm not really sure, but I suspect it outperforms the append solution.

Comment: @AtilaRomero Not sure that this solution has any advantages, but when use reflection for any purposes this is more useful, because it allows to take a key as Value typed directly.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this to `[]string`?

Comment: @AtilaRomero I just tested it, it still panics  when the list grows.

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for. I am trying merge two different "Entity" structs, both of which contain a map[string][]*Foo. So, for the first struct, i need to identify the keys, so i can look it up in the second struct by key, instead of ranging over every map value to see if its they key i want to merge into. Thanks!

Comment: if you need a `[]string` look for blackgreen's answer with generics. `maps.Keys`

Comment: This is a good answer. But also please consider that reflect package should not be used in production code. It's not a good choice.

Answer (score 116):

Go now has generics. You can get the keys of any map with [`maps.Keys`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Keys).

Example usage:

```
    intMap := map[int]int{1: 1, 2: 2}
    intKeys := maps.Keys(intMap)
    // intKeys is []int
    fmt.Println(intKeys)

    strMap := map[string]int{"alpha": 1, "bravo": 2}
    strKeys := maps.Keys(strMap)
    // strKeys is []string
    fmt.Println(strKeys)
```

`maps` package is found in `golang.org/x/exp/maps`. This is experimental and outside of Go compatibility guarantee. They aim to move it into the std lib in <strike>Go 1.19</strike> the future.

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/fkm9PrJYTly

For those who don't like to import exp packages, here's the [source code](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/exp/+/39d4317d:maps/maps.go;l=10) (originally authored by [Ian Lance Taylor](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor)), which as you can see is very simple:

```
// Keys returns the keys of the map m.
// The keys will be an indeterminate order.
func Keys[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](m M) []K {
    r := make([]K, 0, len(m))
    for k := range m {
        r = append(r, k)
    }
    return r
}
```

---

**NOTE**: In Go 1.21 **a part** of the `maps` package has been moved into the standard library, but not `maps.Keys`. For details see the Go issue [maps: remove Keys and Values for Go 1.21](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/61538) tl;dr the `Keys` method might end up having a different signature. So in Go 1.21 the solutions presented here (use `x/exp/maps` or copy the source) are still applicable.

Comment: What is the meaning of `~` in `~map[K]V`?

Comment: @Marko please see [What's the meaning of the new tilde token ~ in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888240/whats-the-meaning-of-the-new-tilde-token-in-go)

Answer (score 24):

I made a sketchy benchmark on the three methods described in other responses.

Obviously pre-allocating the slice before pulling the keys is faster than `append`ing, but surprisingly, the `reflect.ValueOf(m).MapKeys()` method is significantly slower than the latter:

```
❯ go run scratch.go
populating
filling 100000000 slots
done in 56.630774791s
running prealloc
took: 9.989049786s
running append
took: 18.948676741s
running reflect
took: 25.50070649s
```

Here's the code: https://play.golang.org/p/Z8O6a2jyfTH
(running it in the playground aborts claiming that it takes too long, so, well, run it locally.)

Comment: In your `keysAppend` function, you can set the capacity of the `keys` array with `make([]uint64, 0, len(m))`, which drastically changed the performance of that function for me.

Comment: @keithbhunter I agree, there is very little difference.

Comment: @keithbhunter Calling make([]int, len(m)) and make([]int, 0, len(m) are effectivelly the same thing: preallocates array in memory, which would completely defeats the purpose of the test.

Answer (score 17):

A nicer way to do this would be to use `append`:

```
keys = []int{}
for k := range mymap {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
```

Other than that, you’re out of luck—Go isn’t a very expressive language.

Comment: It is less efficient than the original though - append will do multiple allocations to grow the underlying array, and has to update the slice length every call.  Saying `keys = make([]int, 0, len(mymap))` will get rid of the allocations but I expect it will still be slower.

Comment: This answer is safer than using len(mymap), if someone else changes the map while the copy is beeing made.

Comment: @AtilaRomero is that true? I would assume that in such case, data may be corrupted completely, or is this specified somewhere in golang?

Comment: @Petr I think that should panic. There should not be two routines working on the same map. That's what sync.Map should be used for, or use a map with Mutexes

Comment: Concurrent access would cause a data race error, if testing with that enabled.  Definitely something to avoid.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `map` is of type `map[int]string`, you could get keys and values using the [experimental maps package from the standard library](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/exp/maps"
)


func main() {
    mymap := map[int]string{1: "foo", 2: "bar", 3: "biz"}

    fmt.Println(maps.Keys(mymap))
    fmt.Println(maps.Values(mymap))
}
```

Output:

```
[2 3 1]
[bar biz foo]
```

Comment: It should be noted that the order of results from both maps.Keys and maps.Values are indeterminate, so the order of results from one cannot be assumed to match the other.

Answer (score 3):

A generic version (go 1.18+) of `Vinay Pai`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27848197).

```
// MapKeysToSlice extract keys of map as slice,
func MapKeysToSlice[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K {
    keys := make([]K, len(m))

    i := 0
    for k := range m {
        keys[i] = k
        i++
    }
    return keys
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Visit  https://play.golang.org/p/dx6PTtuBXQW

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    mapEg := map[string]string{"c":"a","a":"c","b":"b"}
    keys := make([]string, 0, len(mapEg))
    for k := range mapEg {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)
    fmt.Println(keys)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool lib called [`lo`](https://github.com/samber/lo)

> A Lodash-style Go library based on Go 1.18+ Generics (map, filter, contains, find...)

With this lib you could do many convinient operations like map, filter, reduce and more. Also there are some helpers for `map` type

### Keys

Creates an array of the map keys.

```golang
keys := lo.Keys[string, int](map[string]int{"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
// []string{"bar", "foo"}
```

### Values

Creates an array of the map values.

```golang
values := lo.Values[string, int](map[string]int{"foo": 1, "bar": 2})
// []int{1, 2}
```