# Not double the array size when append

Tags: go, slice

For

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {


    b := make([]int, 1, 5)  
    printSlice("b", b[:cap(b)])
    
    b2 := append(b, 1)
    b3 := append(b2, 1)
    b4 := append(b3, 1)
    b5 := append(b4, 1)
    
    printSlice("bbbb", b5[:cap(b5)])
    
    b6 := append(b5, 1)
    
    printSlice("bbbb", b6[:cap(b6)])
    
    
}

func printSlice(s string, x []int) {
    fmt.Printf("%s len=%d cap=%d %v\n",
        s, len(x), cap(x), x)
}
```

The results is

```
b len=5 cap=5 [0 0 0 0 0]
bbbb len=5 cap=5 [0 1 1 1 1]
bbbb len=10 cap=10 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
```

It looks like the last append double the underlying array size, is there a way to say make it as size 6?

Comment: If you need a specific capacity, you slice or allocate your desired capacity. `append` is most efficient in the general case.

Comment: A possible solution has been proposed here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41551

Answer (score 6):

You can't control the result capacity if you're using the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append). It doesn't document the capacity growth strategy, so there's nothing to expect (except that the elements being appended will fit into it). It usually allocates more than needed, thinking of future growth (to reduce future allocations). [Spec: Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) lists all "guarantees" you have reguarding `append()` and the resulting slice's capacity:

> If the capacity of `s` is not large enough to fit the additional values, `append` allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, `append` re-uses the underlying array.

If you want to control the resulting slice's capacity, you have to allocate it yourself, copy over the old slice and append to the new, e.g.:

```
b6 := make([]int, len(b5), len(b5)+1)
copy(b6, b5)
b6 = append(b6, 1)
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-GT8HlUU88t)):

```
b len=5 cap=5 [0 0 0 0 0]
bbbb len=5 cap=5 [0 1 1 1 1]
bbbb len=6 cap=6 [0 1 1 1 1 1]
```

As you can see, there's a "lot" that needs to be done: new slice to be created (with backing array), old copied over, and then the append operation (this could be optimized by creating the new slice like `make([]int, len(b5)+1)`, then the final append is just `b6[len(b6-1] = 1`). It would be a waste to do these all the time when a single element is appended, that's why `append()` allocates more so this doesn't have to executed all the time.

See related questions:

[Go slices - capacity/length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683911/go-slices-capacity-length/36689864#36689864)

[Golang slice append vs assign performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654729/golang-slice-append-vs-assign-performance/38654841#38654841)

[Insert a value in a slice at a given index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128016/insert-a-value-in-a-slice-at-a-given-index/46130603#46130603)

[Concatenate two slices in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248241/concatenate-two-slices-in-go/40036950#40036950)

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to say make it as size 6?

No. Append does what it does. But nothing stops you from providing a slice with the desired cap.