# Original order of JSON values

Tags: json, go

In my application, I get some unspecified json string and want to loop through the values of the json string. I use the function json.Unmarshal() to get an objectlist from the json values. That works fine. But unfortnely I get an random list of the json values and not the orginal order of them. I use this example code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    jsonstr := `{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata#People/$entity",
    "@odata.id": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"08D956FAB7E22152\"",
    "@odata.editLink": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')",
    "UserName": "russellwhyte",
    "FirstName": "Russell",
    "LastName": "Whyte",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Concurrency": 637636457076498770
}`

    var result interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &result); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't convert json to object.")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    odataobjs := result.(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range odataobjs {
        fmt.Print(fmt.Sprintln(k, v))
    }
}
```

See on [go-playground](https://play.golang.org/p/e5f8kPjzxz8).

This can be some of the result list:

```
@odata.editLink http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')
UserName russellwhyte
Gender Male
Concurrency 6.376364570764988e+17
@odata.id http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')
@odata.etag W/"08D956FAB7E22152"
LastName Whyte
@odata.context http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata#People/$entity
FirstName Russell
```

After first search in www I find out, that a json object is in general an unordered list. Thats okay for me, as long as the list is in original order! I can't build some struct, because the json values are unknown at the runtime!

Have you some ideas for me to get the original value list?

Thanks for this input. I have now the original order.
But: How can i find out the type of the values? string, nil int and float are okay and i get this. But how can i find out the arrays in the json file with this solutions? Like the following JSON, he says that *Emails* is an unknown type. And *AddressInfo* is not listet? So i can't get the sub elements from it.

Json Input:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata#People",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.id": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('vincentcalabrese')",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"08D957CD4BA2C90E\"",
            "@odata.editLink": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('vincentcalabrese')",
            "UserName": "vincentcalabrese",
            "FirstName": "Vincent",
            "LastName": "Calabrese",
            "Emails": [
                "Vincent@example.com",
                "Vincent@contoso.com"
            ],
            "AddressInfo": [
                {
                    "Address": "55 Grizzly Peak Rd.",
                    "City": {
                        "CountryRegion": "United States",
                        "Name": "Butte",
                        "Region": "MT"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Concurrency": 637637361498507534
        }
    ]
}
```

Example Code:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonstr))

    for dec.More() {
        // Read prop name
        t, err := dec.Token()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Err: %v", err)
            break
        }
        var name string
        var ok bool
        if name, ok = t.(string); !ok {
            continue // May be a delimeter
        }

        // Read value:
        t, err = dec.Token()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Err: %v", err)
            break
        }
        //fmt.Printf("Name: %s, Value: %v\n", name, t)

        switch t.(type) {
        case nil:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is nil", name))
        case string:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is string", name))
        case []interface{}:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is array", name))
        case map[string]interface{}:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is map", name))
        case int16:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is int16", name))
        case int32:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is int32", name))
        case int64:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is int64", name))
        case float32:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is float32", name))
        case float64:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is float64", name))
        default:
            logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is unknown type", name))
        }
    }
```

Output

```
@odata.context is string
value is unknown type
@odata.id is string
@odata.etag is string
@odata.editLink is string
UserName is string
FirstName is string
LastName is string
Emails is unknown type
Vincent@example.com is string
```

You have some ideas for it?
Thanks you.

Comment: _"a json object is in general an unordered list. Thats okay for me, as long as the list is in original order!"_ That means it's **not** OK for you and you need it as ordered.

Comment: _That means it's not OK for you and you need it as ordered_
Thats not correct. I don't need a ordered list, i don't want to order the list, i want the original order from json string. Nothing else.

Comment: `logger.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("%s is unhandled type of %T", name, t))`

Answer (score 5):

By default the [`encoding/json`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package uses Go maps to unmarshal JSON objects. Go maps are not ordered, see [Why can't Go iterate maps in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930416/why-cant-go-iterate-maps-in-insertion-order/28931555#28931555) and [In Golang, why are iterations over maps random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925822/in-golang-why-are-iterations-over-maps-random/55925880#55925880)

So if you need the original order, you cannot use maps (implicit or explicit). You may use [`json.Decoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder) and decode the input by tokens, which of course gives you the tokens in the original order.

This is how it could look like to your example:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonstr))

for dec.More() {
    // Read prop name
    t, err := dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Err: %v", err)
        break
    }
    var name string
    var ok bool
    if name, ok = t.(string); !ok {
        continue // May be a delimeter
    }

    // Read value:
    t, err = dec.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Err: %v", err)
        break
    }
    fmt.Printf("Name: %s, Value: %v\n", name, t)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SV0c6oPspA3)):

```
Name: @odata.context, Value: http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata#People/$entity
Name: @odata.id, Value: http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')
Name: @odata.etag, Value: W/"08D956FAB7E22152"
Name: @odata.editLink, Value: http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')
Name: UserName, Value: russellwhyte
Name: FirstName, Value: Russell
Name: LastName, Value: Whyte
Name: Gender, Value: Male
Name: Concurrency, Value: 6.376364570764988e+17
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the json as random list ,you can get it in ascending order using `sort` package.You need to create a slice of your map keys and use the `sort.Strings()` method on it ,then you can iterate your slice and get the data in ascending order.Here is the code for the same:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {

    jsonstr := `{
            "@odata.context": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata#People/$entity",
            "@odata.id": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"08D956FAB7E22152\"",
            "@odata.editLink": "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')",
            "UserName": "russellwhyte",
            "FirstName": "Russell",
            "LastName": "Whyte",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Concurrency": 637636457076498770
        }`

    var result interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &result); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't convert json to object.")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    odataobjs := result.(map[string]interface{})

    keysJson := make([]string, 0, len(odataobjs))
    for k := range odataobjs {
        keysJson = append(keysJson, k)
    }

    sort.Strings(keysJson)

    for _, k2 := range keysJson {
        fmt.Println(k2, odataobjs[k2])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@odata.context http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata#People/$entity
@odata.editLink http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')
@odata.etag W/"08D956FAB7E22152"
@odata.id http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People('russellwhyte')
Concurrency 6.376364570764988e+17
FirstName Russell
Gender Male
LastName Whyte
UserName russellwhyte
```