# recursively flatten a map golang

Tags: json, dictionary, for-loop, go

Using the below json Im trying to flatten it for ease of accessibility.

Example having 2 resource there can be n number of in this structure

```
"config": {
    "type": "r1",
    "properties": {
        "p1": "10",
        "p2": "10"
    },
    "connected": [
        {
            "type": "r3",
            "properties": {
              "p1": "10",
              "p2": "10"
            },
            "connected": [
                {}
        },
    ],
}
```

Custom flatterning logic

```
func keyValuePairs(m interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    kvs := make(map[string]interface{})
    if reflect.ValueOf(m).Kind() == reflect.Map {
        mp, ok := m.(map[string]interface{})
        if ok {
            var key string
            var value interface{}
            for k, v := range mp {
                switch k {
                case "type":
                    key = v.(string)
                case "properties":
                    value = v
                case "connected":
                    if collection, ok := v.([]interface{}); ok {
                        for _, c := range collection {
                            for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(c) {
                                nnv, _ := nv.(map[string]interface{})
                                _, ok := nnv["connectedTo"]
                                if !ok {
                                   nnv["connectedTo"] = key
                                }
                                kvs[nk] = nv
                            }
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(v) {
                        kvs[nk] = nv
                    }
                }
            }
            if key != "" {
                kvs[key] = value
            }
        } else {
            for k, v := range m.(map[string]interface{}) {
                kvs[k] = v
            }
        }
    }
    return kvs
}
```

The desired output is kinda fluctuationg, some runs I get the output what I require and some executions "connectedTo" attribute is empty.

```
{
"r1": {
        "p1": "10",
        "p2": "10"
    },
"r3" : {
        "connectedTo": "r1",
        "p1": "10",
        "p2": "10"
    },
}
```

I think the executions are not sequential. Please do correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: what do you mean by sequential?

Comment: while recursively calling the function sometimes the order is not maintained. Sometimes i observe order as 1,2,3 sometimes its 1,3,2

Comment: maps in go are not ordered. Iterating their keys is pesudo random, if you mean that.

Comment: Okay. But do you have idea why the results is not proper on some executions?

Comment: I dont really get what your code is doing, but I havent really looked at it. I am just saying if you rely on the order of keys, than that is a bug. You cannot rely on the order. Apart from that, its too much relfection for my taste, if your object has a well known structure, you shouldn't need reflection at all, you know what key to pick. If it has connections, you call the function again.

Comment: I wish there was defined struct. Its actually dynamically based on the json we create the resource so "r1" can be top level and also into 2nd or 3rd level. So i thought flatterning the struct will help irrespective of the nested resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iteration order over a map is random. For details, see [Why are iterations over maps random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925822/why-are-iterations-over-maps-random/55925880#55925880) and [How to iterate maps in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930416/how-to-iterate-maps-in-insertion-order/28931555#28931555)

Now look at your loop:

```
var key string
var value interface{}
for k, v := range mp {
    switch k {
    case "type":
        key = v.(string)
    case "properties":
        value = v
    case "connected":
        if collection, ok := v.([]interface{}); ok {
            for _, c := range collection {
                for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(c) {
                    nnv, _ := nv.(map[string]interface{})
                    _, ok := nnv["connectedTo"]
                    if !ok {
                       nnv["connectedTo"] = key
                    }
                    kvs[nk] = nv
                }
            }
        }
    default:
        for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(v) {
            kvs[nk] = nv
        }
    }
}
```

You are using the `key` variable in the `"connected"` branch, but the order in which `"type"` and `"connected"` will be reached is non-deterministic (random).

The `"type"` branch is what sets `key`, but if `"connected"` is reached first, `key` will be empty.

You must not rely on map iteration order.

An easy fix is to first get the value associated with`"type"` first and assign it to `key` (which you use in the `"connected"` branch), **before** the loop.

For example:

```
key, _ := mp["type"].(string)
value := mp["properties"]
// Now process other properties:
for k, v := range mp {
    switch k {
    case "type", "properties": // Already handled
    case "connected":
        if collection, ok := v.([]interface{}); ok {
            for _, c := range collection {
                for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(c) {
                    nnv, _ := nv.(map[string]interface{})
                    _, ok := nnv["connectedTo"]
                    if !ok {
                       nnv["connectedTo"] = key
                    }
                    kvs[nk] = nv
                }
            }
        }
    default:
        for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(v) {
            kvs[nk] = nv
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @icza, i have updated the logic, mistake from my side I used different code. The logic to assign `connectedTo` is under `connected` and not under `default`

Comment: @user8866279 I have updated my answer to reflect your edited code, but doesn't change the fact and reasoning.

Comment: Thank you. Tested and working as expected.