# How to print each elements string with its frequency based on index in map - Golang

Tags: string, dictionary, go

Let say I have input and output string where the output will be the frequency of each elements in the string and the char itself

```
input := "programming"
output := "p2ro2ga2min"
```

How can I print it based on index after I found the freq of distinct character

This is my code

```
func countFreq(s string)  {
    sMap := make(map[string]int)

    for _, v := range s {
        sMap[string(v)]++
    }

    for i, v := range sMap {
        fmt.Printf("%v%v", i, v)
    }

    // Don't know what to do next

}

The output of code is 
output: n1p1r2o1g2a1m2i1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting `rune`s, so use a map of `map[rune]int`, so you can omit the conversions back to `string`.

[Maps are unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930416/how-to-iterate-maps-in-insertion-order/28931555#28931555), so if you want the output in the same order as the input, you can't (shouldn't) iterate over the map.

Once you counted the letters, range over the *input* letters again, and get the frequency from the map, and remove it. If the count is greater than 1, also print the number.

```
func countFreq(s string) {
    sMap := make(map[rune]int)

    for _, v := range s {
        sMap[v]++
    }

    for _, v := range s {
        count := sMap[v]
        if count == 0 {
            continue // Char already printed and removed
        }
        delete(sMap, v)
        if count > 1 {
            fmt.Print(count)
        }
        fmt.Print(string(v))
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
for _, s := range []string{"programming", "ab", "aba", "aabcdeac"} {
    fmt.Println("In:", s)
    fmt.Print("Out: ")
    countFreq(s)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/qlOELuHKzMs)):

```
In: programming
Out: p2ro2ga2min
In: ab
Out: ab
In: aba
Out: 2ab
In: aabcdeac
Out: 3ab2cde
```

Answer (score 2):

@icza's answer is great. Here's an alternative that I thought of before but only just got around to writing.

It uses a string to keep track of the rune order but you could use a string builder if speed is important.

```
func countFreq(s string) {
    sMap := make(map[rune]int)
    sOut := ""

    for _, c := range s {
        sMap[c]++
        if sMap[c] == 1 {
            sOut += string(c)
        }
    }

    for _, c := range sOut {
        if sMap[c] > 1 {
            fmt.Print(sMap[c])
        }
        fmt.Printf("%c", c)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and explanation. I need some time to understand how the code works since I am still trying to understand how the map works