# Map in order range loop

Tags: loops, dictionary, go, hashmap, for-range

I'm looking for a definitive way to range over a `Go` `map` in-order.

[Golang spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) states the following:

> The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next. If map entries that have not yet been reached are removed during iteration, the corresponding iteration values will not be produced. If map entries are created during iteration, that entry may be produced during the iteration or may be skipped. The choice may vary for each entry created and from one iteration to the next. If the map is nil, the number of iterations is 0.

All I've found here on StackOverflow and Googling are (**imho**) workarounds that I don't like.

Is there a solid way to iterate through a map and retrieve items in the order they've been inserted?

The solutions I've found are:

- Keep track of keys and values in two separate slices: which sounds like "Do not use a map", losing all the advantages of using maps.
- Use a map but keep track of keys in a different slice: this means data duplication which might lead to data misalignment and eventually may bring loads of bugs and painful debugging.

What do you suggest?

---

Edit in response to the possible duplicate flag.

There's a slight difference between my question and the one provided ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330781/sort-go-map-values-by-keys), but also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342784/how-to-iterate-through-a-map-in-golang-in-order)), both questions asked for looping through the map following the keys lexicographic order; I, instead, have specifically asked:

> Is there a solid way to iterate through a map and **retrieve items in the order they've been inserted**?

which is not lexicographic and thus different from [`@gramme.ninja` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330781/sort-go-map-values-by-keys):

> How can I get the keys to be in order / sort the map so that the keys are in order and the values correspond?

Comment: Map only. When need to iterate: _Collect_ keys, sort, iterate, done.

Comment: My question regards looping using the order the keys have been inserted, not to loop using the keys ordered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort golang map values by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330781/sort-golang-map-values-by-keys)

Comment: @Flimzy I've updated the question addressing the possible duplicate flag, I think the questions are related but **not** the same, thus the flag is not correct. Hope I've been clearer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need a `map` and keys in order, those are 2 different things, you need 2 different (data) types to provide that functionality.

#### With a keys slice

The easiest way to achieve this is to maintain key order in a different slice. Whenever you put a new pair into the map, first check if the key is already in it. If not, add the new key to the separate slice. When you need elements in order, you may use the keys slice. Of course when you remove a pair, you also have to remove it from the slice too.

The keys slice only has to contain the keys (and not the values), so the overhead is little.

Wrap this new functionality (map+keys slice) into a new type and provide methods for it, and hide the map and slice. Then data misalignment cannot occur.

Example implementation:

```
type Key int   // Key type
type Value int // Value type

type Map struct {
    m    map[Key]Value
    keys []Key
}

func New() *Map {
    return &Map{m: make(map[Key]Value)}
}

func (m *Map) Set(k Key, v Value) {
    if _, ok := m.m[k]; !ok {
        m.keys = append(m.keys, k)
    }
    m.m[k] = v
}

func (m *Map) Range() {
    for _, k := range m.keys {
        fmt.Println(m.m[k])
    }
}
```

Using it:

```
m := New()
m.Set(1, 11)
m.Set(2, 22)
m.Range()
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wqhstzhBQT).

#### With a value-wrapper implementing a linked-list

Another approach would be to wrap the values, and –along the real value– also store the next/previous key.

For example, assuming you want a map like `map[Key]Value`:

```
type valueWrapper struct {
    value Value
    next  *Key // Next key
}
```

Whenever you add a pair to the map, you set a `valueWrapper` as the value, and you have to *link* this to the previous (last) pair. To *link*, you have to set `next` field of the last wrapper to point to this new key. To easily implement this, it's recommended to also store the last key (to avoid having to search for it).

When you want to iterate over the elements in insertion order, you start from the first (you have to store this), and its associated `valueWrapper` will tell you the next key (in insertion order).

Example implementation:

```
type Key int   // Key type
type Value int // Value type

type valueWrapper struct {
    v    Value
    next *Key
}

type Map struct {
    m           map[Key]valueWrapper
    first, last *Key
}

func New() *Map {
    return &Map{m: make(map[Key]valueWrapper)}
}

func (m *Map) Set(k Key, v Value) {
    if _, ok := m.m[k]; !ok && m.last != nil {
        w2 := m.m[*m.last]
        m.m[*m.last] = valueWrapper{w2.v, &k}
    }
    w := valueWrapper{v: v}
    m.m[k] = w
    if m.first == nil {
        m.first = &k
    }
    m.last = &k
}

func (m *Map) Range() {
    for k := m.first; k != nil; {
        w := m.m[*k]
        fmt.Println(w.v)
        k = w.next
    }
}
```

Using it is the same. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ih-ZvaGXsl).

**Notes:** You may vary a couple of things to your liking:

- You may declare the internal map like `m map[Key]*valueWrapper` and so in `Set()` you can change the `next` field without having to assign a new `valueWrapper`.
- You may choose `first` and `last` fields to be of type `*valueWrapper`
- You may choose `next` to be of type `*valueWrapper`

#### Comparison

The approach with an additional slice is easier and cleaner. But removing an element from it may become slow if the map grows big, as we also have to find the key in the slice which is "unsorted", so it's `O(n)` complexity.

The approach with linked-list in value-wrapper can easily be extended to support fast element removal even if the map is big, if you also add the `prev` field to the `valueWrapper` struct. So if you need to remove an element, you can super-fast find the wrapper (`O(1)`), update the prev and next wrappers (to point to each other), and perform a simple `delete()` operation, it's `O(1)`.

Note that deletion in the first solution (with slice) could still be sped up by using 1 additional map, which would map from key to index of the key in the slice (`map[Key]int`), so delete operation could still be implemented in `O(1)`, in exchange for greater complexity. Another option for speeding up could be to change the value in the map to be a wrapper, which could hold the actual value and the index of the key in the slice.

See related question: [Why can't Go iterate maps in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930416/why-cant-go-iterate-maps-in-insertion-order)

Comment: Defining a new type wrapping map+slice didn't occur to my mind. Still working around, but it feels much cleaner and safer and at this point I don't think there's anything much cleaner.

Comment: Here is a fork where Range takes a callback: https://play.golang.org/p/fBgAEu-Zpw

Comment: Thanks a lot to both! 
Great answer!

Comment: @FredMaggiowski Added example implementations to both approaches.

Comment: @icza yeah, I've seen, thanks! I've also seen the notes regarding the second example and I agree with using `*valueWrapper`. Anyhow I think I'll go with the first example (map+slice) since it seems to be the easiest one to maintain.. You did a great work! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @FredMaggiowski Added a Comparison section. Yes, additional slice is clearer / easier. The linked-list in wrapper solution can be faster for removal operation if map grows big.

Comment: sure thing, I don't think that in this case the Map will grow that big ;)