# How to FIFO Order a Map during Unmarshalling

Tags: go, mapping, fifo

I know from reading around that Maps are intentionally unordered in Go, but they offer a lot of benefits that I would like to use for this problem I'm working on. My question is how might I order a map FIFO style? Is it even worth trying to make this happen? Specifically I am looking to make it so that I can unmarshal into a set of structures hopefully off of an interface.

I have:

```
type Package struct {
    Account   string
    Jobs      []*Jobs
    Libraries map[string]string
}

type Jobs struct {
// Name of the job
     JobName string `mapstructure:"name" json:"name" yaml:"name" toml:"name"`
// Type of the job. should be one of the strings outlined in the job struct (below)
     Job *Job `mapstructure:"job" json:"job" yaml:"job" toml:"job"`
// Not marshalled
     JobResult string
// For multiple values
     JobVars []*Variable
}

type Job struct {
// Sets/Resets the primary account to use
    Account *Account `mapstructure:"account" json:"account" yaml:"account" toml:"account"`
// Set an arbitrary value
    Set *Set `mapstructure:"set" json:"set" yaml:"set" toml:"set"`
// Contract compile and send to the chain functions
    Deploy *Deploy `mapstructure:"deploy" json:"deploy" yaml:"deploy" toml:"deploy"`
// Send tokens from one account to another
    Send *Send `mapstructure:"send" json:"send" yaml:"send" toml:"send"`
// Utilize eris:db's native name registry to register a name
    RegisterName *RegisterName `mapstructure:"register" json:"register" yaml:"register" toml:"register"`
// Sends a transaction which will update the permissions of an account. Must be sent from an account which
// has root permissions on the blockchain (as set by either the genesis.json or in a subsequence transaction)
    Permission *Permission `mapstructure:"permission" json:"permission" yaml:"permission" toml:"permission"`
// Sends a bond transaction
    Bond *Bond `mapstructure:"bond" json:"bond" yaml:"bond" toml:"bond"`
// Sends an unbond transaction
    Unbond *Unbond `mapstructure:"unbond" json:"unbond" yaml:"unbond" toml:"unbond"`
// Sends a rebond transaction
    Rebond *Rebond `mapstructure:"rebond" json:"rebond" yaml:"rebond" toml:"rebond"`
// Sends a transaction to a contract. Will utilize eris-abi under the hood to perform all of the heavy lifting
    Call *Call `mapstructure:"call" json:"call" yaml:"call" toml:"call"`
// Wrapper for mintdump dump. WIP
    DumpState *DumpState `mapstructure:"dump-state" json:"dump-state" yaml:"dump-state" toml:"dump-state"`
// Wrapper for mintdum restore. WIP
    RestoreState *RestoreState `mapstructure:"restore-state" json:"restore-state" yaml:"restore-state" toml:"restore-state"`
// Sends a "simulated call" to a contract. Predominantly used for accessor functions ("Getters" within contracts)
    QueryContract *QueryContract `mapstructure:"query-contract" json:"query-contract" yaml:"query-contract" toml:"query-contract"`
// Queries information from an account.
    QueryAccount *QueryAccount `mapstructure:"query-account" json:"query-account" yaml:"query-account" toml:"query-account"`
// Queries information about a name registered with eris:db's native name registry
    QueryName *QueryName `mapstructure:"query-name" json:"query-name" yaml:"query-name" toml:"query-name"`
// Queries information about the validator set
    QueryVals *QueryVals `mapstructure:"query-vals" json:"query-vals" yaml:"query-vals" toml:"query-vals"`
// Makes and assertion (useful for testing purposes)
    Assert *Assert `mapstructure:"assert" json:"assert" yaml:"assert" toml:"assert"`
}
```

What I would like to do is to have jobs contain a map of string to Job and eliminate the `job` field, while maintaining order in which they were placed in from the config file. (Currently using viper). Any and all suggestions for how to achieve this are welcome.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Why can't Go iterate maps in insertion order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930416/why-cant-go-iterate-maps-in-insertion-order); and [Golang map in order range loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450120/golang-map-in-order-range-loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to hold the keys in a separate slice and work with that.

```
type fifoJob struct {
    m map[string]*Job
    order []string
    result []string
    // Not sure where JobVars will go. 
}

func (str *fifoJob) Enqueue(key string, val *Job) {
    str.m[key] = val
    str.order = append(str.order, key)
}

func (str *fifoJob) Dequeue() {
    if len(str.order) > 0 {
        delete(str.m, str.order[0])
        str.order = str.order[1:]
    }
}
```

Anyways if you're using `viper` you can use something like the `fifoJob` struct defined above. Also note that I'm making a few assumptions here.

```
type Package struct {
    Account   string
    Jobs      *fifoJob
    Libraries map[string]string
}

var config Package
config.Jobs = fifoJob{}
config.Jobs.m = map[string]*Job{}

// Your config file would need to store the order in an array.
// Would've been easy if viper had a getSlice method returning []interface{}
config.Jobs.order = viper.GetStringSlice("package.jobs.order") 

for k,v := range viper.GetStringMap("package.jobs.jobmap") {

    if job, ok := v.(Job); ok {
        config.Jobs.m[k] = &job
    }
}
```

for

PS: You're giving too many irrelevant details in your question. I was asking for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It would appear that my hope of making something easily unmarshal-able for a json list that would enable iterable mapping by FIFO is not going to be easy and probably best to ignore atm. But thanks. This helped a lot.

Comment: It would be possible if you implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface.  But how easy it would be, depends on your exact problem.

Comment: Note that if your map is big, then maintaining a sorted list of keys will slow things down.  I hit this problem with a hashmap on the order of 10M entries and had to rethink this approach.  In the end, a combined hashmap and queue data structure worked like a charm.

Comment: right but I'm basically taking a list of jobs from a yaml/json file and trying to keep them in order and this appears to make my job more difficult, not less.

Comment: @RichardJohnCatalano If you can share the structure, I can see if implimenting the `json.Unmarshaler` interface can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maps are by nature unordered but you can fill up a slice instead with your keys. Then you can range over your slice and sort it however you like. You can pull out specific elements in your slice with [i].

Check out pages 170, 203, or 204 of some great examples of this:

[Programming in Go](http://books.google.de/books?id=HW-5SZ1HKusC&pg=PT217&lpg=PT217&dq=%224.3.4%20Key-Ordered%20Map%20Iteration%22&source=bl&ots=Fp7245_0iv&sig=IhJnSkLX2hFA021V2XkBPRiREf4&hl=de#v=onepage&q=%224.3.4%20Key-Ordered%20Map%20Iteration%22&f=false)