# Sorting a map by value and put it in another map in GO

Tags: arrays, sorting, go

I want to sort this map by value,in descending order( from the most of like to the less of likes ) and put it on the same map or another one with this ordre
My map:

```
   m := make(map[int]int)
   for train := range *trainings{
   l,_:= db.NumberOfLikes(train,train.TrainingId)
   m[train.TrainingId]=l
   }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Maps in go are hash maps. You can't sort them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Go map values by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330781/sort-go-map-values-by-keys)

Comment: @alessiosavi it doesn't cause he sorted an array (of the values) not the map :/

Comment: @Marc there is no solution to sort a map at all ?

Comment: No, use a different data structure.

Comment: @Marc like an object ?

Comment: For example slices can be sorted

Answer (score 1):

The [Go blog: Go maps in action][1] has an excellent explanation.

> When iterating over a map with a range loop, the iteration order is
> not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration
> to the next. Since Go 1 the runtime randomizes map iteration order, as
> programmers relied on the stable iteration order of the previous
> implementation. If you require a stable iteration order you must
> maintain a separate data structure that specifies that order.

```golang
m := map[string]int{"Alice": 23, "Eve": 2, "Bob": 25}

keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))
for k := range m {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
sort.Strings(keys)

for _, k := range keys {
    fmt.Println(k, m[k])
}
```

Comment: here he does copy the values in an array and sort the array and display values, he doesn't sort the map

Comment: I think that you have not read the explaination: `When iterating over a map with a range loop, the iteration order is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next`

Comment: A map in Go cannot be sorted, so this is the correct answer.

Comment: but a slice can't contain both the id and the number of like that this training has , or am I wrong ? @TehSphinX

Comment: A slice can contain structs that can contain any information you need. You can create a struct type `Training` that has the ID and all training data in it. Then you can create `var trainings []Training` and you can sort that with `sort.Slice` and a custom sort function. e.g. by ID: `sort.Slice(trainings, func(i, j int) bool {return trainings[i].ID < trainings[j].ID})`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but likes aren't in training data, to contextualize, I have a struct with all training data (Training id, date, .... but doesn't contain likes) , and I have a separate  stuct for likes that has the training id and some other information in it , and I need to sort and display trainings by number of likes  @TehSphinX

Comment: Then maybe your data could look like this: `var trainings []struct {
  Likes    int
  training Training
 }`