# golang i use fmt.Println() after println() but

Tags: go

this is my code(golang)

```
func main() {
    names := []string{"1", "2", "3"}

    for index, name := range names {
        println(index, name)
    }

    myMap := map[string]string{
        "A": "Apple",
        "B": "Banana",
        "C": "Charlie",
    }

    for key, val := range myMap {
        fmt.Println(key, val)
    }
}
```

and this is result

```
0 1
B Banana
1 2
2 3
C Charlie
A Apple
```

1. Why was it names and myMap mixed?
2. Why different order of myMap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [golang map prints out of order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108215/golang-map-prints-out-of-order)

Comment: First, the easy one: 

   2. Map is different order

Like @Akavall commented, this is explained is explained in his link. The gist of it is hash tables.

   1. This is a curious one, going trough the code of fmt package, it simply writes in a buffer and then writes it. Running your code 100 times in console with different variations runtime.GOMAXPROCS I could not reproduce it and it always printed the full array and then the map, however, your behavior happens when I ran it on IntelliJ with the Go plugin. Are you using it or are you trying on console? You might have stumbled on a plugin bug.

Comment: thank you. I ran it on intellij.

Comment: @Akavall: This question is **not** an exact duplicate. Exact duplicate: This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [func println](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println)
>
> ```
> func println(args ...Type)
> ```
>
> The println built-in function formats its arguments in an
>   implementation-specific way and writes the result to standard error.
>
> [func Println](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println)
>
> ```
> func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> fmt.Println formats using the default formats for its operands and
>   writes to standard output.

fmt.Println writes to standard output (stdout) and println writes to standard error (stderr), two different, unsynchronized files.

> [Map types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)
>
> A map is an unordered group of elements of one type, called the
>   element type, indexed by a set of unique keys of another type, called
>   the key type.
>
> [For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> A "for" statement specifies repeated execution of a block.
>
> The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed
>   to be the same from one iteration to the next.

Maps elements are unordered. The iteration order is not specified.