# Go - loop through map on the same order multiple times

Tags: go

How can I loop through a map on a constant order multiple times ?

In my go code I am looping through a map twice but the values are not appearing on the same order on both loops :

`fieldMap := map[string]int{...}`

First loop :

`for k, _ := range fieldMap {...}`

Second loop :

`for _, v := range fieldMap {...}`

Comment: This cannot be done with a map alone http://stackoverflow.com/a/11853555/1072106.

Comment: Looping over a map gives an intentionally randomized iteration order. If yo want a consistent iteration order, you have to extract the keys and sort them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the keys in the first loop and use them in the second loop:

```
keys := make([]string, 0, len(m))
for k, v := range m {
    fmt.Println(k, v)
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
for _, k := range keys {
    fmt.Println(k, m[k])
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/MstH20wkNN.

Comment: It definitaly works but is there any way to do it without creating an array in addition to the map ?

Comment: Firstly, `keys` is a slice, not an array. Secondly, no. The order of map iteration is not guaranteed. If you want to reliably iterate over a map in a certain order, you need to create that order yourself.

Comment: I agree with your general point that you need to create that order themselves. 

I just wanted to add that while `keys` is a slice, it will be backed by an array. I assume the reason for the question was that they didn't want to allocate any more memory, and slices aren't free.

Answer (score 4):

Go makes sure that you cannot rely on a map's order as stated in this blog post https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_7.

> When iterating over a map with a range loop, the iteration order is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next. Since Go 1 the runtime randomizes map iteration order, as programmers relied on the stable iteration order of the previous implementation. If you require a stable iteration order you must maintain a separate data structure that specifies that order.

Ainar-G's answer is correct, but here is a variation of it while incorporating this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/27848197/3536948

```
keys := make([]string, len(m))
i := 0
for k, _ := range m {
    keys[i] = k
    i += 1
}
for _, k := range keys {
    fmt.Println(m[k])
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/64onPZNODm

Comment: thankyou for you're answer which explains me why it's made like so.