# Go's maps under the hood

Tags: dictionary, pointers, go, hashmap

After reading Dave Cheney's [blogpost](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/05/29/how-the-go-runtime-implements-maps-efficiently-without-generics) about Go's maps there is still few things unclear to me.

TLDR:

- **Why are they unordered?**
- **Where actual values are stored in memory?**

After digging in [runtime](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/map.go) package I found out that underlying map structure is following:

```golang
// A header for a Go map.
type hmap struct {
    // Note: the format of the hmap is also encoded in cmd/compile/internal/gc/reflect.go.
    // Make sure this stays in sync with the compiler's definition.
    count     int // # live cells == size of map.  Must be first (used by len() builtin)
    flags     uint8
    B         uint8  // log_2 of # of buckets (can hold up to loadFactor * 2^B items)
    noverflow uint16 // approximate number of overflow buckets; see incrnoverflow for details
    hash0     uint32 // hash seed

    buckets    unsafe.Pointer // array of 2^B Buckets. may be nil if count==0.
    oldbuckets unsafe.Pointer // previous bucket array of half the size, non-nil only when growing
    nevacuate  uintptr        // progress counter for evacuation (buckets less than this have been evacuated)

    extra *mapextra // optional fields
}
```

`buckets` - is array of buckets where indexes is low-order bits of key's hash, where the bucket is:

```golang
// A bucket for a Go map.
type bmap struct {
    // tophash generally contains the top byte of the hash value
    // for each key in this bucket. If tophash[0] < minTopHash,
    // tophash[0] is a bucket evacuation state instead.
    tophash [bucketCnt]uint8
    // Followed by bucketCnt keys and then bucketCnt elems.
    // NOTE: packing all the keys together and then all the elems together makes the
    // code a bit more complicated than alternating key/elem/key/elem/... but it allows
    // us to eliminate padding which would be needed for, e.g., map[int64]int8.
    // Followed by an overflow pointer.
}
```

..well it's just array of `uint8` where every item is first byte of key's hash. And key-value pairs are stores as `key/key value/value` (eight pairs per bucket). But where exactly? Considering that map may contain value of (almost) any type. There should be some kind of pointer to place in memory where array of values stored, but `bmap` doesn't have such info.

And since key's hashes are located in ordered array inside bucket, why it's order different every time I looping over map?

Comment: See [Go: what determines the iteration order for map keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619479/go-what-determines-the-iteration-order-for-map-keys)

Comment: They are unordered for the same reason that maps/dictionaries/hashes in most languages are unordered: speed. The majority of cases don't need them ordered, which would make ordering them in all cases wasteful of CPU resources. This was (I think) a sensible tradeoff by the designers, but if you want to know why they chose that... you would have to ask them, not the community at large.

Comment: "why it's order different every time I looping over map?" so that people would not rely on any particular ordering, as the ordering is not guaranteed in any way by the language. "Where actual values are stored in memory?" yes, in memory, wherever the map has been allocated - this question is kind of unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - **Why are they unordered?**

Because this gives *greater freedom* to the runtime to implement the map type. Although we know Go's (current) implementation is a hashmap, the language specification allows to use any map implementation like hash map, tree map etc. Also not having to remember the order, this allows the runtime to do its job more effectively and using less memory.

Adrian's comment nicely summarizes that order is rarely needed, and it would be a waste to always maintain order. When you do need order, you may use a data structure that provides the ordering. For examples, see [Map in order range loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450120/map-in-order-range-loop/39450454#39450454).

> And since key's hashes are located in ordered array inside bucket, why it's order different every time I looping over map?

The Go authors intentionally made map's iteration order randomized (so we mortals don't get dependent on a fixed order). For more, see [In Golang, why are iterations over maps random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925822/in-golang-why-are-iterations-over-maps-random/55925880#55925880)

Also see related: [Why can't Go iterate maps in insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930416/why-cant-go-iterate-maps-in-insertion-order/28931555#28931555)

> - **Where actual values are stored in memory?**

The "where" is specified by `hmap.buckets`. This is a pointer value, it points to an array in memory, an array holding the buckets.

```
buckets    unsafe.Pointer // array of 2^B Buckets. may be nil if count==0.
```

So `hmap.buckets` points to a contiguous memory segment holding buckets. A bucket is "modeled" by `bmap`, but this is not its actual memory layout. A bucket starts with an array holding top hash bytes of keys being in the bucket (`tophash [bucketCnt]uint8`), and this array is **followed by `bucketCnt` keys of the bucket, which is then followed by `bucketCnt` values of the bucket**. Lastly there is an overflow pointer.

Think of the bucket like this *conceptual* type, which "visualizes" where keys and values are located in memory:

```
type conceptualBucket struct {
    tophash     [bucketCnt]uint8
    keys        [bucketCnt]keyType
    values      [bucketCnt]valueType
    overflowPtr uintptr
}
```

Note: `bucketCnt` is a compile time constant being `8`, it is the maximum number of key/elem pairs a bucket can hold.

Of course this "picture" is inaccurate, but it gives the idea where / how keys and values are stored.